# Error cannot load such file — nokogiri/nokogiri *Could it be my destination folder?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm having a problem running a ruby file for twitter and I install nokogiri, and ausca as instructed. For some reason when I try to run the file, it gives me this error:

> C:\Users\jonathan>C:\Users\jonathan.gem\ruby\2.2.0\bin\twitter_bot.rb
>   C:/Users/jonathan/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
>   .rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)

There was a bunch more errors after this but im assuming that it's mainly because of this one. I tried to run sudo command to install it but sudo doesn't work for me in command prompt with ruby. I just want to run a basic ruby file and nothing crazy so please help. Thanks in advance, stayed up all night trying to get this to work.

Here is my results for gem env:

C:\Users\jonathan\Ruby>gem env

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
- RUBY VERSION: 2.2.1 (2015-02-26 patchlevel 85) [x64-mingw32]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/jonathan/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Users/jonathan/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/jonathan/Ruby/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/jonathan/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x64-mingw32
- GEM PATHS:

  - C:/Users/jonathan/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - C:/Users/jonathan/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:

  - C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo Edit 8\
  - C:\Windows\system32
  - C:\Windows
  - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
  - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  - C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
  - C:\Users\jonathan\Ruby\bin

Comment: rubyinstaller.org/downloads states that "64-bit versions of Ruby are relatively new on the Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with it." Plus, you're using the bleeding-edge ruby version.  You may want to try the x64 version of Ruby 2.1.5 (or even Ruby 2.0.0-p643).  YMMV.

Comment: Thank you, I decided to use the 32bit version of 1.9 and it worked.

Comment: Same problem here. In RubyInstaller 2.1.5 x64 nokogiri worked fine but there was another unrelated little bug causing segmentation fault on certain conditions; noticing that RubyInstaller 2.2.1p85 was just released I gladly switched to it, but now I have this problem with nokogiri.. Anyone knows of a possible quick fix?